# if statement to skip certain values in loop

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have a range of `X` and `Y` values, and I have a domain that I don't want to calculate the values of nodes within. I want to have an `if` statement within a loop in Matlab to skip these.

For example:

- Range: `X = [1:20]` and `Y = [1:20]`.
- I want to ignore nodes in this range: `X = [5:7]` and `Y = [12:14]`.

I think the code should be something like this:

```
for X=1:20
    for Y=1:20
        if X=5:7 & Y=12:14
            return
        end
        % the operation here !
        T(X,Y) = lab lab lab
    end
end
```

However, I'm not sure how to properly write the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ismember` or a combination of `any` and `==` for the condition, and `continue` is the command for skipping to the next loop index...

```
% ismember example
for X = 1:20
    for Y = 1:20
        if ismember( X, 5:7 ) && ismember( Y, 12:14 )
            continue
        end
        % your loop operations
    end
end
```

In this case, you could replace the `if` condition with

```
if any( X == 5:7 ) && any( Y == 12:14 )
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose an alternative to Wolfie's solution to generate all indices in advance, and then apply a single loop:

```
Xvect = repmat(X, length(Y), 1);
Yvect = repmat(Y, 1, length(X));
Xvect = Xvect(:);
Yvect = Yvect(:);

Xis5to7 = (Xvect >= 5) & (Xvect <= 7);
Yis12to14 = (Yvect >= 12) & (Yvect <= 14);
XYcomb = ~(Xis5to7 & Yis12to14); % This is the range to exclude, negate it.

allX = Xvect(XYcomb);
allY = Yvect(XYcomb);
(par)for i = 1 : length(allX);
   X = allX(i);
   Y = allY(i);
   Ltemp(i) = ...;
end
L(XYcomb) = Ltemp;
```

The advantage is to have combinations `(allX, allY)` displayed up front plus due to a single loop it is very suitable to make a `parfor` out of it.