# Adding unique values into csv , from reading csv file

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, unique

I have csv file, I am reading data from it and writing it in other csv file. I am checking if the first 4 letters of particular line are "AGCS" then I will add that line in csv file and if the letters are different then I have to merge all the lines to single line and then add in csv file.

```
with open('New_Theme.csv', 'r') as inf, open("New_Theme1.csv", "w") as outf:
data = []
z1 = 0
reader = csv.reader(inf)
csv_rows = [row for row in reader]
# temp = ""
for row in csv_rows:
    # print(type(row))
    # print(row)
    if row[z1][0:4] == 'AGCS':
        data = row
        print(data)
        xy = " ".join(data)
        outf.write(xy + "\n")

    else:
        if row not in data:
            data = data + row
            print(data)
            xy = " ".join(data)
            outf.write(xy + "\n")
```

**[input]**
Project Key,Jmp Issue,Summary,Updated,Created,Comments

AGCSPSR AGCSPSR-369 Onerous"

contract testing"

refinement"

AGCSPSR,AGCSPSR-380,Switc

**Output[wrong]**
Project Key,Jmp Issue,Summary,Updated,Created,Comments

AGCSPSR AGCSPSR-369 Onerous"

AGCSPSR AGCSPSR-369 Onerous contract testing"

AGCSPSR AGCSPSR-369 Onerous contract testing refinement"

AGCSPSR,AGCSPSR-380,Switch

**Output[Expected]**
Project Key,Jmp Issue,Summary,Updated,Created,Comments

AGCSPSR AGCSPSR-369 Onerous contract testing refinement"

AGCSPSR,AGCSPSR-380,Switch

Comment: understanding your problem is not easy with so much data. If you provide a sample that data that is small but with the same characteristics as your original data, you help us to help you.  E.h. if 5 columns do not contribute only show one column with a dummy value "other value", etc.

Comment: Can you give  a try now?

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is adding sentences that have been added before.

You need to squeeze in a conditional statement that doesn't add previous added values. It can also be done by using a conditional statement that check whether or not the previous value is the same as the new one by checking a larger part of the data (e.g. checking up until `row[z1][0:10]`

Comment: Can you please help me with the code, I tried the logic you suggested previously but that doesn't work

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Can you show me the code? As I said, a conditional statement that checks previously added values should do the job

Comment: else:
        if row not in data:
            data = data + row
            print(data)
            xy = " ".join(data)
            outf.write(xy + "\n")

Comment: You just copied and pasted the else statement which can be read already. That's not what I meant though. You could create an if statement inside of your if statement. The ```else``` has nothing to do with checking for added values since the added values don't comply with that.  Also, have you tried putting the ```print(data)``` statement outside of your for loop? Cause right now, it's printing data that's been iterated over already.

Comment: Not sure about the if condition which you are asking to add. If you can help me with that it will be great. Yes I have tried keeping the print statement outside the for loop, I am still not getting the expected result

Comment: What don't you get exactly? As I said, you're adding values that have been added before since there's no other conditional statement for skipping a value that has been added before. You should look into these links for more information on what I mean: [continue statement](https://geek-university.com/the-continue-statement/), [skipping values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51134367/if-statement-to-skip-certain-values-in-loop). You should look into Python documentation to learn things like this as well